# Differential Pulse Code Modulation

Tags: network

In dpcm, do we transmit the difference between the consecutive samples or the difference between the samples and their predicted values. I've seen both of these definitions in different websites so I am confused.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are variations, but DPCM usually means the difference between the current and the *predicted* value ("Option 2"). "Option 1" using the simple differences between two values requires a higher bandwidth.